# Cannot convert tuple to a list in python

Tags: python, list, computer-science

Entering the correct syntax but still cannot convert a tuple to list in python.
[image: alt]

Comment: Please put your code in the question next time.

Comment: I have attached the image containing the code.

I am copying the code here also:

>>> list('hello')
hello
>>> list(('cat','dog',5))
('cat', 'dog', 5)
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t
(1, 2, 3)
>>> list(t)
(1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like your `list` function is not what you expect it to be. (I imagine there's something like `list = print` or something similar somewhere.)

What happens if you just enter `list`? It should show `<class 'list'>` or similar.

Comment: Ohh, I just saw the code again and figured out that I created a function named 'list'. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure given only the linked code, but it looks like you have overwritten `list` with something else that just returns or prints its argument. To recover it, you could just restart the interpreter or do `real_list = type([])`.

Comment: I just saw the code again and figured out that I created a function named 'list'. Thanks :)

Comment: Just because I created that function, that function is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What python version are you using on the image example?

[I replicated all your steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrzXw.png) with all versions I have on my computer (Python2.6, Mac's native Python2.7, brewmaster's  Python2.7, Python3) and none of them gave me the same output as yours.

Maybe I didn't understood your subject?

Comment: I just went through my code and figured out that earlier I created a function named 'list' in the same window of IDLE, this caused the problem. Problem solved. Thanks :)